# Conditional Grouping - SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, conditional-statements, grouping

In SQL Server Report Builder 2.0, can a conditional grouping be created utilizing the standard functions that are available?

In my dataset, I have some rows that return NULL for a particular field, and I do not want them included in the grouping.

Sample Data Set

```
ID    Description    Inventory    Purchase
 1    an inventory   inv1         null
 2    an inventory2  inv2         null
 3    a purchase     null         pur1
```

I want the grouping to be on ID and Inventory, but exclude items that are null.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you just need to add a condition to the `WHERE` clause of your query, something like this:

```
SELECT …
FROM   …
WHERE  …
  AND  Inventory IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  ID,
  Inventory
```

Unless I'm missing something, of course.